# PDF does not contain EOF marker (PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError) with pdf-reader

Tags: ruby, pdf, rubygems, stringio, pdf-reader

I am using ‘pdf-reader’ gem to read raw contents of pdf documents so I can post (http-post) them to an API. To confirm the API implementation can create a valid pdf document from the raw content, I wrote a small [gist](https://gist.github.com/som-poddar/8137c986b37e036444bc) to validate my code to read the pdf content.

For some reason, I always keep getting ‘PDF does not contain EOF marker (PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError)’.

Can anyone point me out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Posting the PDF file you are writing would be more helpful. The 'most likely' explanation is that you are doing CR/LF translation which will invalidate the declared startxref offset (ie the xref won't start at the declared location).