# Ruby - How to add EOF marker into a PDF file or otherwise bypass PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError: PDF does not contain EOF marker

Tags: ruby, file, pdf, mechanize, pdf-reader

I'm using the `Mechanize` ruby gem to click a button on the web to download a PDF file and save it to the local file system.

```
URL = "www.my-site.com"
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.pdf = Mechanize::File # FYI I have also tried Mechanize::FileSaver and Mechanize::Download here

page = agent.get(URL)
form = page.forms.first
button = page.form.button_with(:value => "Some Button Text")

local_file = "path/to/file.pdf"
response = agent.submit(form, button)
response.save_as(local_file)
```

But when I try to read this PDF file using the `PDF::Reader` gem, I get an error "PDF does not contain EOF marker".

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new(local_file) # this also happens if I try to use PDF::Reader.new(response.body) and PDF::Reader.new(response.body_io) depending on the different pluggable_parser configurations mentioned above
#> PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError: PDF does not contain EOF marker
```

I'm able to save the PDF locally and view it and it looks fine, but the `PDF::Reader` gem is complaining about it missing an EOF marker.

So my question is: is there a way I could add an EOF marker into the PDF or something to get around this error so I can parse the PDF?

Thanks.

Related (unanswered) question: [PDF does not contain EOF marker (PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError) with pdf-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612426/pdf-does-not-contain-eof-marker-pdfreadermalformedpdferror-with-pdf-reader)

Related Docs:

- http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/File.html
- http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Download.html
- http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/FileSaver.html
- https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader

EDIT:

I found the EOF marker somewhere in the middle of the downloaded file contents, followed by some HTML-looking stuff that I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of. I want to isolate the PDF content and then parse that, but still running into issues. Here is the full script I am using:
https://gist.github.com/s2t2/c6766846d024edd696586b2bc7fee0bf

Comment: Have you tried just appending an EOF to the end of the document?

Comment: How can one do that?

Comment: The best way would be to reconsider the content being saved (`response.save(local_file)`)... but you might try opening the PDF with a different Ruby reader (i.e., CombinePDF or a pdftk based reader) and see if they can overcome the error... though it's better to not have an error than to dynamically fix it every tine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the website you're accessing: http://employmentsummary.abaquestionnaire.org

The add HTML data at the end of the response.

However, you could truncate the response by searching for the first substring `%EOF` and removing all the data after that.

i.e.:

```
pdf_data = result.body
pdf_data.slice!(0, pdf_data.index("%EOL").to_i + 4)
if(pdf_data.length <= 4)
   # handle error
else
   # save/send pdf_data
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `ArgumentError: string contains null byte`. Can you share a working script based on my gist?

Comment: @s2t2 I'm away from my computer at the moment, but this issue sounds like a String encoding issue. Perhaps try changing the string to binary encoding before you manipulate it's content?